# FirebaseListAdapter Access to key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Im using Google Firebase and FirebaseUI

I am passing a list of values to a FirebaseListAdapter like so

```
 ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot requestSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                requestList request = requestSnapshot.getValue(requestList.class);
                Log.i("Chat", request.getTitle()+": "+request.getDescription()+"    "+request.getKey());
            }
```

I want to store the index of the record (Key) along with the information within. However as the fields automatically map themselves if they are the same name, this leaves my unable to work it out.

I have tried calling the properties of the "key" methods within the requestList class by the name "key" however this hasnt worked

The returned data structure looks like this

```
    Key:{
    "RequestTitle":"Value",
    "RequestDescription":"description",
    "RequestItems":{ item 1 item 2}
}
```

The requests class looks like this

```
public class requestList {

    String RequestTitle;
    String RequestDescription;
    String key;

    public requestList() {
    }

    public requestList(String RequestTitle, String RequestDescription, String key) {
        this.RequestTitle = RequestTitle;
        this.RequestDescription = RequestDescription;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return RequestTitle;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return RequestDescription;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `requestSnapshot.getValue(requestList.class)` you are taking the JSON *value* from the database and turning it into a `requestList` object. The *key* is not part of that.

However, you can easily call `requestSnapshot.getKey()` to get the key of each snapshot.

If you want to keep both the key and the value, it might be worth simply keeping the `DataSnapshot` since that contains both of them.

Comment: Am I able to pass the key through to requestList, then everything is stored in the same class /instance?

Comment: It already is all stored in a single class: the `DataSnapshot`. You can of course also pass everything into a `requestList`, but you'll have to inject the key yourself. `DataSnapshot.getValue()` won't do that for you.

Comment: +Frank van Puddelen, thanks for you help on this. Im going to attempt to pass the requestSnapshot to the requestList Class and implement setting of the variable manually

Comment: Im unable to figure this out. If i change the requestList class to accept a DataSnapshot and not string the object is always null. How do i pass the dataSnapshot to the requestList class?

Comment: Would you be able to explain how to pass the DataSnaphot correctly. For some reason the setting of the requestKey is not retained outside of the onDataChange method.

Comment: `DataSnapshot` instances are not reused in any way. The Firebase SDK also won't reuse your `requestList`. So if you're seeing information disappear between calls, it must either happen in your code or in some other code that we can't see from here. If you have a look at the adapters in our [FirebaseUI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database), you'll see we keep snapshots and Java objects between calls without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ive upvoted the answer above because i couldnt have dont it with the input, however here is the working answer

i changed my requestList class to include a setKey method and then called this from within the onDataChange method. Not sure if its the correct method, but it certainly solves the problem

```
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot requestSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            //requestList request = requestSnapshot.getValue(requestList.class);
            requestList request = requestSnapshot.getValue(requestList.class);
            request.setKey(requestSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.i("Chat", request.getTitle()+": "+request.getDescription()+"    "+request.getKey());
        }
    }
```

and the requestList Class

```
public class requestList {

    String RequestTitle;
    String RequestDescription;
    String key;

    DataSnapshot requestSnapshot;


    public requestList() {
    }

    public requestList(DataSnapshot requestSnapshot) {
        //this.RequestTitle = RequestTitle;
        //this.RequestDescription = RequestDescription;
        //this.key = key;

        this.requestSnapshot = requestSnapshot;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return RequestTitle;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return RequestDescription;
    }


    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```